# Multinomial theorem and binomial factor (case for Bosons)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bosons

I am trying to understand the meaning behind the binomial factor and multinomial theorem when dealing with problems in statistical mechanics, mostly combinatoric related problems. This is the problem  that I am currently dealing with:

A particle can be in 10 different energy states. Now we have 2 indistinguishable boson particles, and for them we want to find the nr of possible microstates in which the system can be found:

The solution is :

$ [( 2 + 10 - 1)!] / [2!(10 - 1)!]$

What is the logic behind this expression and how did we reach it?
I want to understand the logic behind the  expression. I know that my problem starts with the binomial expression, what it means in combinatoric, and only after I understand that I can go to the multinomial theorem. Can anyone provide a detailed and comprehensive explanation as to how these formulas come to be and how they help in the above problem?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combinatory problem is considering all permutations of 2 particles and 9 separatrices, illustrated as follow:

[image: fig-1]

Two bluse lines denotes the two indistinguished boson particles, and the 9 red lines each one is a separatrix between two consecutive energy levels. The first part in the figure represents a configuration of state $\vert 1,1 \rangle$, the second is $\vert 3,8 \rangle$, and the third $\vert 6,10 \rangle$.

Each of the different permutation of these 11 lines  (2 blue line and 9 red lines) represente a configuration. The total number of permutation is:

$$
   N_{total} = \frac{11!}{2!\,9!}.
$$